# How to create xml file from existing xsd file?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to create XML file with data(data is from database) using existing XSD file. Please guide me how to do this in C#

Comment: you create an xml file from C# classes (generated with XSD) and validate it against the XSD. I think google will give you a some directions. (google: xml C# xsd will prolly give you a nice kick start)

Comment: [I wish people would search first!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530424/generating-an-xml-file-using-xsd-file).

Comment: Sorry, from 2days am checking in net. am getting soluntion to use xsd.exe to get xml file and that i have to include in my VS project. but am getting confused how to create xml file by using that and putting data into that

Comment: -1: "I'm getting confused" is not enough to explain problems you are facing - and it is even harder when question does not have any sample code (i.e. from comments it looks like you can't save XML to a file, but it is not clear if it is the actual road block you are hitting)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

1. Use [`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) to create a set of class definitions from your schema.
2. Populate instances of those classes from the database.
3. Use `XmlSerializer` to serialize those instances to XML.

Comment: Yes i used xsd.exe for creating xml file,but its giving error saying "can only generate one of classes or datasets" and not able to find where the xml will get saved

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how to use XSD.EXE?  You can't specify both `/classes` and `/dataset`.  The output will be in the current folder unless you use the /o flag.  And it doesn't create XML files - it creates .CS (class) files.