# Serialize multiple data xsd xml

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

sorry if is like a duplication but I need help, I followed this answer [generating xml based on xsd schema (with .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808506/generating-xml-based-on-xsd-schema-with-net)
To serialize data, and "works" but I'm stuck here:

```
var data = new capType { tel = new[] {
       new telType { source = "buffalo", time = 1 }
    } };
```

I want to add a lot more fields and items, but I dont know how.

Thanks in advance! And sorry my English!

Edit: I want this design if helps in any way.

```
<PRESENTATION>
    <INFORMATION type="RI">
        <SPECIFICATION>
            <REGIME code="1">
                <REQUEST code="1">
                    <DETAIL handle="true" type="NORMAL" period="2017-11-30">
                        <FILE path="/20171031/BALANCE.TXT"/>
                    </DETAIL>
                </REQUEST>
            </REGIME>
        </SPECIFICACION>
    </INFORMATION>
</PRESENTATION>
```

Comment: have you actually performed the step outlined in the answer you link: xsd /classes schema.xsd  for you schema?

Comment: Yes, I have the .cs and works with one field, but I dont know how get the design of output adding more fields

Comment: Probably better to post the code you do have rather than quote the code from the link.