# c# - How to create XML with subrows

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I'm new for c# and XML.
I have xsd file and created cs file from it like described here [Generating XML file using XSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530424/generating-xml-file-using-xsd-file)
Now I need to generate XML file that contains multiple invoices and every invoice has 1 or more subrows. 
How to do that?

Comment: What are you tried?

Comment: Try to google it, it can help.

Comment: I did google, closest example is probably here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx
But there looks like only one OrderItem. But if I have many?

Comment: Example is typeof(MyClass)   you can changed this in typeof(List<MyClass>)  and voilla

Answer (score 0):

1 start VS command prompt

2 generate classes, based on XSD with SvcUtil.exe

```
svcutil xml_in_arved.xsd /language:C# /dataContractOnly /importxmltypes   /out:class.cs
```

3 write code to fill classes

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book>" +
                    "  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>" +
                    "  <price>5.95</price>" +
                    "</book>");

invoices invoices = new invoices();
invoices.Nodes = new XmlNode[2];
invoices.Nodes[0] = doc.CreateNode("element", "test", "myNamespace");
invoices.Nodes[1] = doc.CreateNode("element", "tes2", "myNamespace");
```

4 serialize classes to xml

**Serialize example**

```
var content = invoices;
var filename = @"c:\temp\xmlserialise.xml";
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(content.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, content);
}
```

Comment: I'm using this xsd http://wiki.directo.ee/_media/et/xml_in_arved.xsd
Generated classes. 
How to fill classes?

Comment: OK, probably this is right answer, I just don't know how to use it. Like I posted, I'm new to c#.
First I generated classes like this xsd.exe /classes xml_in_arved.xsd and it gave me bigger cs file than using svcutil xml_in_arved.xsd /language:C# /dataContractOnly /importxmltypes   /out:class.cs
Not sure which one is right.

Comment: look at the difference what is generated and what fits your need. Our job is also some reseach and exploring.