# Problems creating an xml file using an xsd file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

I need to create an XML file from an XSD file via a class. I'm new to programming so I followed this tutorial to make my first test XML and it worked out fine: [Generating XML file using XSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530424/generating-xml-file-using-xsd-file)

But now i gotta do it with a bigger XSD, creating a bigger XML looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test-xml xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Mod0>
    <K0_1 KnZ="0.1">Input1</K0_1>
    <K0_2 KnZ="0.2">Input2</K0_2>
    <K0_3 KnZ="0.3">Input3</K0_3>
  </Mod0>
  <Mod1>
    <K1_1 KnZ="1.1">Input1</K1_3>
    <K1_2 KnZ="1.2">Input2</K1_4>
    <K1_3 KnZ="1.3">Input3</K1_4>
  </Mod1>
</test-xml>
```

My Problem is, that the tutorial doesn't create an XML File looking like this.

1. It would only use `<test-xml>` and `<Mod0>` as elements, without `<K0_1>` up to `<K0_3>` but i need all of these elements
2. Also it would just stop at `<Mod0>`, but I need `<Mod0>` up to `<Mod18>`
3. And at last, I didn't get `KnZ="0.1"` etc. before the Input like in my example code

I created the class using the xsd.exe tool based of my XML schema just like in the tutorial in step 1 but now I don't know how to code so that my XML looks like I showed in the example code above.

Can anyone help me with that? I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have bigger XSD? Show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

The presented XML structure is very questionable. It is not a good idea to use running numbers in the XML element names.

It is much better to modify it as follows:

- **Mod** element is using an attribute for numbering, i.e. `<Mod id="0">`
- **K** element drops numbers completely, i.e. `<K>`

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test-xml xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Mod id="0">
        <K KnZ="0.1">Input1</K>
        <K KnZ="0.2">Input2</K>
        <K KnZ="0.3">Input3</K>
    </Mod>
    <Mod id="1">
        <K KnZ="1.1">Input1</K>
        <K KnZ="1.2">Input2</K>
        <K KnZ="1.3">Input3</K>
    </Mod>
</test-xml>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I totally agree with you but sadly it's not on me to decide how the XML structure looks like. I have to keep it the way i showed in my example. Therefore I would be wondering if you know a way how I could code to get the XML structure that I showed above. The videos and documentations i've seen showed similar things to what you did and i also prefer it that way, sadly it's not an option for me though.

Comment: No XSD will work with dynamic XML element names.

Comment: Ok i see. So it's not possible with C#, but is it possible somehow or isn't it possible at all? The only thing that worked so far was using the "XML Schema Explorer" in Visual Studio and just use the function "Generate Sample XML". I got the XML File exactly the way i want and need to, but i need to automate the process and that won't be possible with the XML Schema Explorer i guess. Especially because i couldn't put in the Input i want to.

Comment: It is not related to c#. Just think about it. You need to define XML structure and data types via XSD.  Element and attribute names are constant. Just element and attribute values could be dynamic

Comment: Thanks again. I got another question and i'm sorry if it sounds stupid, like I said i'm new to programming and might not understand something immediately. The Element and attribute names (<xml-test>, <Mod1>, <Mod2>, <K1_1>, <K1_2>, <K2_1>, KnZ etc.) are defined in the XSD that i have. Therefore i would just need to fill those values, right? In the class that is created I also got the elements and attributes.That is where my coding skills aren't good enough because i don't know how to fill the values of those already defined elements and attributes in the right structure like in my example.

Comment: Or is it not possible at all even if all of these element names like <Mod1>, <Mod2> etc. are defined in the XSD because to create an XML File i would have to have the same element name(like u have in ur example)?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add your XSD.

Comment: I posted a 2nd answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the provided XSD. Crazy stuff. All my previous comments are right on target. The XSD is so big becuase it mushrooms similar elements with running number in the name.

In any case, I used [Free Online XSD to XML Converter](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-to-xml-converter) to generate XML file based on the XSD.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsozial-ba xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Mod0>
    <M0_1 KnZ="27.92">99079</M0_1>
    <M0_2 KnZ="2.55">72</M0_2>
    <M0_3 KnZ="8.88">XSozial-BA-SGBII-Version-4.7.0</M0_3>
    <M0_4 KnZ="42.7">B</M0_4>
    <M0_5 KnZ="43.3">2?"i@+O** Q").9</M0_5>
    <M0_6 KnZ="01.5">1993-12</M0_6>
    <M0_7 KnZ="2.50">2</M0_7>
    <M0_8 KnZ="6.4">1991-10-15T07:49:42.41</M0_8>
    <M0_9 KnZ="5.7">string</M0_9>
    <M0_10 KnZ="0.2">string</M0_10>
    <M0_11 KnZ="96.31">string</M0_11>
  </Mod0>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="53.3">1997-02-04T20:06:35.92</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="59.6">1996-01-03</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="6.52">2006-04-10</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="2.96">-1035960</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="4.91">-323560</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="64.0">-434850</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="50.52">-946190</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="57.58">-4517520</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="69.52">3546560</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="36.96">-2689910</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="8.84">323430</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="1.08">-4039730</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="6.29">4143840</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="4.3">53490</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="4.43">-3294270</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="35.6">-4457420</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="94.2">3675630</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="5.23">-1500170</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="5.9">2701080</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="8.59">1428750</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="05.5">4831640</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="01.75">-772490</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="16.3">4249040</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="80.47">-2078190</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="7.4">1944800</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="5.5">-2477650</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="0.3">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="2.7">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="3.2">2003-04-10T15:04:00.32</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="1.36">2009-02-27</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="99.02">2003-11-27</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="06.0">419950</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="04.28">1755100</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="8.2">189910</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="66.7">-2927070</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="87.06">-4779500</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="58.70">2035670</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="00.78">-2355280</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="5.17">-781560</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="1.9">-375510</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="13.81">-1954930</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="25.63">4396840</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="48.2">-4610720</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="3.9">2199970</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="0.7">2007480</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="92.2">-4517430</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="01.12">1572730</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="2.71">882600</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="3.7">-4651460</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="20.65">-2000710</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="1.43">2650</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="20.3">3447560</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="9.0">-4908420</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="5.29">-2389780</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="7.5">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="02.2">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="4.39">1972-03-15T01:07:11.07</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="7.9">2018-06-23</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="79.9">1990-09-20</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="2.5">3073880</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="60.2">4130920</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="1.9">336810</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="69.94">4515090</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="40.91">-4127340</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="1.40">858060</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="55.38">4615830</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="73.56">210160</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="9.08">-3908580</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="9.9">-2980490</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="8.3">2025480</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="90.9">-2365230</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="9.80">4466820</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="5.37">519040</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="37.92">872340</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="02.82">2558650</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="4.12">1821630</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="23.7">2068090</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="8.62">2416020</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="57.25">-1816340</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="93.79">-4509440</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="6.50">4405600</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="6.5">-235070</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="0.72">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="07.04">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="0.23">1998-08-14T04:53:37.38</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="8.98">2005-02-25</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="79.19">2008-07-11</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="4.55">-3704920</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="73.8">-263030</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="84.80">57590</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="36.6">940690</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="94.9">3917120</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="51.6">-105510</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="2.6">-4765710</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="21.15">-3850180</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="09.5">3601460</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="4.3">520130</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="14.6">-1178340</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="38.72">-507960</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="0.3">2918570</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="4.1">1901600</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="20.1">4635770</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="9.7">1927940</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="2.85">4947460</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="4.10">1938930</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="2.0">-4122950</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="55.0">1571370</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="2.2">1466590</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="67.9">-2800</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="7.60">-3522600</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="6.7">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="84.76">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="6.15">2017-04-11T11:08:24.94</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="48.7">1988-02-23</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="29.0">2009-08-14</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="5.54">-1765470</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="31.2">2976520</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="05.3">2047360</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="0.3">703830</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="4.6">4807270</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="56.6">-1216620</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="0.99">3731860</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="18.92">-4935910</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="1.26">4485410</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="1.77">-3966440</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="54.56">459660</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="9.1">-1667630</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="9.8">-592010</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="1.2">2150560</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="1.47">-3996040</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="4.25">4332830</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="01.00">4192800</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="4.15">3229440</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="4.6">223130</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="20.5">-4835520</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="0.9">785250</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="8.3">4643610</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="80.9">954990</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="55.38">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="72.8">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod2>
    <M2_1 KnZ="7.84">81788BG1441265</M2_1>
    <M2_25 KnZ="48.7">string</M2_25>
    <M2_3 KnZ="5.09">7</M2_3>
    <M2_4 KnZ="4.3">2018-05-17T09:18:32.82</M2_4>
    <M2_7 KnZ="0.49">1997-12-15</M2_7>
    <M2_10 KnZ="17.8">2011-05-21</M2_10>
    <M2_11 KnZ="79.0">78</M2_11>
    <M2_12 KnZ="54.5">9</M2_12>
    <M2_13 KnZ="59.3">6</M2_13>
    <M2_14 KnZ="61.0">16</M2_14>
    <M2_16 KnZ="01.23">532616.23</M2_16>
    <M2_17 KnZ="0.3">696766.23</M2_17>
    <M2_18 KnZ="10.73">789585.23</M2_18>
    <M2_26 KnZ="70.8">2010-03-05</M2_26>
    <M2_27 KnZ="09.3">2005</M2_27>
    <M2_28 KnZ="1.49">743031.23</M2_28>
    <M2_29 KnZ="3.18">172483.23</M2_29>
    <M2_30 KnZ="7.59">684711.23</M2_30>
    <M2_31 KnZ="3.16">string</M2_31>
    <M2_32 KnZ="8.27">string</M2_32>
  </Mod2>
  <Mod2>
    <M2_1 KnZ="40.33">02122BG6526060</M2_1>
    <M2_25 KnZ="30.0">string</M2_25>
    <M2_3 KnZ="44.4">4</M2_3>
    <M2_4 KnZ="7.5">1987-01-19T04:21:54.89</M2_4>
    <M2_7 KnZ="5.1">1994-10-08</M2_7>
    <M2_10 KnZ="6.5">2017-02-24</M2_10>
    <M2_11 KnZ="0.2">25</M2_11>
    <M2_12 KnZ="36.80">28</M2_12>
    <M2_13 KnZ="7.86">8</M2_13>
    <M2_14 KnZ="7.53">6</M2_14>
    <M2_16 KnZ="08.06">242118.23</M2_16>
    <M2_17 KnZ="03.46">297682.23</M2_17>
    <M2_18 KnZ="1.1">367004.23</M2_18>
    <M2_26 KnZ="9.7">1993-06-21</M2_26>
    <M2_27 KnZ="6.04">2005</M2_27>
    <M2_28 KnZ="92.1">788827.23</M2_28>
    <M2_29 KnZ="1.3">623526.23</M2_29>
    <M2_30 KnZ="40.1">653595.23</M2_30>
    <M2_31 KnZ="7.42">string</M2_31>
    <M2_32 KnZ="3.8">string</M2_32>
  </Mod2>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="7.03">783c180142</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="05.45">79029BG2201373</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="99.0">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="1.22">7</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="6.7">1972-01-18T19:06:27.20</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="8.1">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="9.1">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="6.2">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="8.2">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="3.2">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="7.0">ABC</M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="6.75">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="8.74">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="0.6">54414</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="25.8">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="38.86">2003-10-26</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="8.00">W</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="8.3">_1Q0HUuNJ2b_</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="45.32">036</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="60.34">78</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="4.0">5</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="24.4">9</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="0.4">false</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="29.7">3</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="2.7">1</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="4.0">1</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="33.17">65</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="6.1">7</M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="82.8">7</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="29.94">7</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="47.87">3</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="0.0">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="36.55">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="71.94">830q236679</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="90.82">08861BG3180182</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="50.51">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="1.10">9</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="0.19">2016-04-26T12:37:35.14</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="07.8">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="80.7">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="90.4">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="2.01">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="0.00">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="5.31"></M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="45.95">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="39.10">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="36.84">13520</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="4.96">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="18.0">2019-11-22</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="5.1">,</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="7.49">G____Y2OVrOP</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="8.33">527</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="9.07">29</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="52.0">3</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="4.5">6</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="8.4">false</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="6.19">46</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="54.40">1</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="56.3">true</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="9.39">32</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="6.88">6</M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="44.2">5</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="6.28">1</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="00.23">4</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="2.29">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="7.1">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="50.48">249k697353</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="1.8">78065BG0911821</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="9.43">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="1.8">1</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="15.83">1986-12-16T03:32:36.64</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="5.0">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="4.7">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="0.4">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="9.22">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="81.3">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="50.84"></M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="15.7">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="68.5">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="4.99">47940</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="84.53">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="9.18">2010-09-07</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="0.60">,</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="29.45">gSk7_58F6bQD</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="7.3">986</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="6.7">4</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="9.7">2</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="26.81">2</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="57.94">1</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="61.60">359</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="07.6">false</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="39.10">1</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="6.22">68</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="2.82">4</M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="2.48">6</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="4.12">1</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="52.1">1</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="68.46">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="19.9">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="41.35">758q315020</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="45.79">28099BG4695630</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="70.04">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="3.84">8</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="53.28">1982-01-13T05:36:48.27</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="4.5">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="15.2">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="12.0">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="80.32">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="9.5">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="9.5"></M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="81.7">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="07.9">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="44.65">30629</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="80.44">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="73.78">2008-10-08</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="5.7">,</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="0.1">0hi7_245QYN_</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="69.57">441</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="78.4">29</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="84.7">7</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="95.7">1</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="77.2">1</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="32.08">99</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="2.0">false</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="4.1">1</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="35.10">39</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="88.00"></M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="86.32">1</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="3.9">3</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="46.0">8</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="8.0">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="0.0">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="86.2">2234138078</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="7.0">46048BG6406738</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="9.7">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="56.6">9</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="71.47">1994-07-12T21:35:55.77</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="92.33">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="8.4">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="3.40">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="46.0">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="0.8">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="4.26">ABC</M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="82.07">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="27.15">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="55.42">73388</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="62.55">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="5.3">1992-01-03</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="9.5">W</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="5.2">hv_1Zv_cR7_2</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="89.05">132</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="5.34">4</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="45.4">4</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="7.4">9</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="90.05">false</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="05.4">03</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="18.89">true</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="77.28">1</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="38.6">77</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="09.71">7</M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="7.5">1</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="5.9">9</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="25.54">5</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="81.3">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="6.2">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod4>
    <M4_1 KnZ="04.67">516C002312</M4_1>
    <M4_2 KnZ="8.27">85358BG1042986</M4_2>
    <M4_9 KnZ="9.7">string</M4_9>
    <M4_3 KnZ="69.1">6</M4_3>
    <M4_4 KnZ="49.60">1998-06-12T06:22:53.10</M4_4>
    <M4_5 KnZ="2.4">438</M4_5>
    <M4_6 KnZ="81.8">226308.23</M4_6>
    <M4_7 KnZ="35.45">1991-06-01</M4_7>
    <M4_8 KnZ="41.8">1988-09-26</M4_8>
    <M4_10 KnZ="1.66">string</M4_10>
    <M4_11 KnZ="8.93">string</M4_11>
  </Mod4>
  <Mod4>
    <M4_1 KnZ="26.82">852_861079</M4_1>
    <M4_2 KnZ="3.3">87906BG5376272</M4_2>
    <M4_9 KnZ="68.16">string</M4_9>
    <M4_3 KnZ="9.84">7</M4_3>
    <M4_4 KnZ="57.4">1990-06-15T18:02:23.88</M4_4>
    <M4_5 KnZ="4.6">762</M4_5>
    <M4_6 KnZ="7.74">48054.23</M4_6>
    <M4_7 KnZ="44.93">1988-10-05</M4_7>
    <M4_8 KnZ="6.92">2017-05-23</M4_8>
    <M4_10 KnZ="9.21">string</M4_10>
    <M4_11 KnZ="2.04">string</M4_11>
  </Mod4>
  <Mod4>
    <M4_1 KnZ="44.1">560_573498</M4_1>
    <M4_2 KnZ="5.6">06723BG8509320</M4_2>
    <M4_9 KnZ="1.6">string</M4_9>
    <M4_3 KnZ="9.36">3</M4_3>
    <M4_4 KnZ="7.59">1985-02-07T14:30:32.30</M4_4>
    <M4_5 KnZ="0.06">608</M4_5>
    <M4_6 KnZ="70.0">163284.23</M4_6>
    <M4_7 KnZ="64.2">2012-02-03</M4_7>
    <M4_8 KnZ="63.4">1989-03-06</M4_8>
    <M4_10 KnZ="4.1">string</M4_10>
    <M4_11 KnZ="3.23">string</M4_11>
  </Mod4>
  <Mod4>
    <M4_1 KnZ="30.8">953_608374</M4_1>
    <M4_2 KnZ="0.94">02902BG8790208</M4_2>
    <M4_9 KnZ="7.52">string</M4_9>
    <M4_3 KnZ="83.74">2</M4_3>
    <M4_4 KnZ="47.87">1977-10-06T12:02:47.54</M4_4>
    <M4_5 KnZ="5.3">667</M4_5>
    <M4_6 KnZ="6.99">893683.23</M4_6>
    <M4_7 KnZ="34.41">2016-08-28</M4_7>
    <M4_8 KnZ="43.47">1983-03-15</M4_8>
    <M4_10 KnZ="8.7">string</M4_10>
    <M4_11 KnZ="17.4">string</M4_11>
  </Mod4>
  <Mod5>
    <M5_1 KnZ="82.9">8398640296</M5_1>
    <M5_2 KnZ="64.2">98431BG8790232</M5_2>
    <M5_9 KnZ="2.1">string</M5_9>
    <M5_3 KnZ="0.0">6</M5_3>
    <M5_4 KnZ="62.4">2019-03-22T15:17:14.43</M5_4>
    <M5_5 KnZ="20.04">145</M5_5>
    <M5_6 KnZ="6.93">70433.23</M5_6>
    <M5_10 KnZ="36.4">58</M5_10>
    <M5_11 KnZ="40.8">126736.23</M5_11>
    <M5_13 KnZ="33.30">string</M5_13>
    <M5_14 KnZ="5.73">string</M5_14>
  </Mod5>
  <Mod7>
    <M7_1 KnZ="82.1">423_519620</M7_1>
    <M7_2 KnZ="03.0">48032BG3955047</M7_2>
    <M7_12 KnZ="5.2">string</M7_12>
    <M7_3 KnZ="21.14">8</M7_3>
    <M7_4 KnZ="84.42">2002-09-12T07:42:56.87</M7_4>
    <M7_6 KnZ="56.4">565598.23</M7_6>
    <M7_8 KnZ="9.03">10</M7_8>
    <M7_9 KnZ="4.1">988534.23</M7_9>
    <M7_10 KnZ="1.2">766323.23</M7_10>
    <M7_14 KnZ="0.4">268945.23</M7_14>
    <M7_15 KnZ="4.7">36217.23</M7_15>
    <M7_16 KnZ="71.22">string</M7_16>
    <M7_17 KnZ="63.8">string</M7_17>
  </Mod7>
  <Mod8>
    <M8_1 KnZ="77.31">915B189370</M8_1>
    <M8_2 KnZ="2.9">11439BG3859455</M8_2>
    <M8_10 KnZ="66.17">string</M8_10>
    <M8_3 KnZ="5.0">4</M8_3>
    <M8_4 KnZ="63.5">1996-03-28T14:55:21.87</M8_4>
    <M8_6 KnZ="9.02">318</M8_6>
    <M8_7 KnZ="5.12">955557.23</M8_7>
    <M8_8 KnZ="57.4">2018-03-05</M8_8>
    <M8_9 KnZ="89.8">1977-04-08</M8_9>
    <M8_11 KnZ="48.5">string</M8_11>
    <M8_12 KnZ="7.33">string</M8_12>
    <M8_13 KnZ="52.4">string</M8_13>
  </Mod8>
  <Mod10>
    <M10_1 KnZ="78.54">820m873680</M10_1>
    <M10_20 KnZ="5.27">string</M10_20>
    <M10_4 KnZ="00.84">1998-01-21T15:54:38.32</M10_4>
    <M10_5 KnZ="83.6">5</M10_5>
    <M10_6 KnZ="86.0">2005-10-09</M10_6>
    <M10_7 KnZ="7.9">2002-06-03</M10_7>
    <M10_8 KnZ="47.19">15</M10_8>
    <M10_9 KnZ="30.45">97</M10_9>
    <M10_10 KnZ="2.1">1974</M10_10>
    <M10_13 KnZ="77.65">false</M10_13>
    <M10_16 KnZ="69.44">1987-06-19</M10_16>
    <M10_21 KnZ="2.6">8</M10_21>
    <M10_23 KnZ="0.31">7</M10_23>
    <M10_28 KnZ="36.20">40158938</M10_28>
    <M10_29 KnZ="3.2">95338014</M10_29>
    <M10_30 KnZ="2.0">1993-03-20T00:55:27.15</M10_30>
    <M10_31 KnZ="67.5">2</M10_31>
    <M10_32 KnZ="0.13">true</M10_32>
    <M10_33 KnZ="7.06">7</M10_33>
    <M10_34 KnZ="10.34">string</M10_34>
    <M10_35 KnZ="10.35">string</M10_35>
  </Mod10>
  <Mod11>
    <M11_1 KnZ="80.33">074l382106</M11_1>
    <M11_11 KnZ="8.2">string</M11_11>
    <M11_4 KnZ="3.21">2005-01-22T01:35:47.34</M11_4>
    <M11_5 KnZ="05.4">1998-11-08</M11_5>
    <M11_6 KnZ="9.55">2011-10-28</M11_6>
    <M11_7 KnZ="2.14">5</M11_7>
    <M11_10 KnZ="64.93">54</M11_10>
    <M11_14 KnZ="14.42">87447767</M11_14>
    <M11_15 KnZ="52.15">17</M11_15>
    <M11_16 KnZ="11.56">1996-06-03T03:46:31.43</M11_16>
    <M11_17 KnZ="52.0">false</M11_17>
    <M11_18 KnZ="43.66">string</M11_18>
    <M11_19 KnZ="1.4">string</M11_19>
  </Mod11>
  <Mod12>
    <M12_1 KnZ="59.48">711H885079</M12_1>
    <M12_15 KnZ="20.78">string</M12_15>
    <M12_4 KnZ="74.21">1982-09-23T12:16:04.42</M12_4>
    <M12_5 KnZ="9.6">1</M12_5>
    <M12_10 KnZ="45.25">0</M12_10>
    <M12_16 KnZ="3.1">2</M12_16>
    <M12_17 KnZ="6.8">5</M12_17>
    <M12_18 KnZ="9.7">true</M12_18>
    <M12_19 KnZ="0.3">string</M12_19>
    <M12_20 KnZ="97.5">string</M12_20>
  </Mod12>
  <Mod13>
    <M13_1 KnZ="0.75">738D383042</M13_1>
    <M13_33 KnZ="6.6">string</M13_33>
    <M13_4 KnZ="66.29">2006-11-24T12:58:05.00</M13_4>
    <M13_5 KnZ="2.79">1990-01-28</M13_5>
    <M13_7 KnZ="1.6">1981-02-13</M13_7>
    <M13_8 KnZ="3.76">2067</M13_8>
    <M13_10 KnZ="36.9">50</M13_10>
    <M13_12 KnZ="5.6">09845139</M13_12>
    <M13_13 KnZ="47.61">421479.23</M13_13>
    <M13_16 KnZ="61.4">5</M13_16>
    <M13_35 KnZ="86.95">string</M13_35>
    <M13_36 KnZ="1.0">28</M13_36>
    <M13_37 KnZ="12.4">1998-07-21T04:31:32.86</M13_37>
    <M13_38 KnZ="6.8">79296731</M13_38>
    <M13_39 KnZ="80.56">7</M13_39>
    <M13_40 KnZ="63.8">string</M13_40>
    <M13_41 KnZ="48.7">string</M13_41>
  </Mod13>
  <Mod14>
    <M14_1 KnZ="6.4">944c687231</M14_1>
    <M14_18 KnZ="88.8">string</M14_18>
    <M14_4 KnZ="71.28">1994-07-11T02:46:34.93</M14_4>
    <M14_7 KnZ="34.1">57</M14_7>
    <M14_14 KnZ="4.1">1980-07-27</M14_14>
    <M14_15 KnZ="03.8">1972-02-06</M14_15>
    <M14_16 KnZ="9.9">2008-04-02</M14_16>
    <M14_17 KnZ="1.7">1988-05-03</M14_17>
    <M14_19 KnZ="76.5">string</M14_19>
    <M14_20 KnZ="8.56">string</M14_20>
  </Mod14>
  <Mod15>
    <M15_1 KnZ="5.24">2016-03-10T11:18:31.47</M15_1>
    <M15_4 KnZ="2.1">1330</M15_4>
    <M15_5 KnZ="74.7">4850</M15_5>
    <M15_6 KnZ="52.74">94</M15_6>
    <M15_7 KnZ="9.5">4124</M15_7>
    <M15_8 KnZ="14.2">string</M15_8>
    <M15_9 KnZ="00.11">1981-08-07</M15_9>
    <M15_10 KnZ="79.0">1982-09-11</M15_10>
    <M15_11 KnZ="51.7">52</M15_11>
    <M15_15 KnZ="53.41">99914</M15_15>
    <M15_16 KnZ="56.31">string</M15_16>
    <M15_17 KnZ="54.72">string</M15_17>
    <M15_18 KnZ="91.12">69730972</M15_18>
    <M15_19 KnZ="81.7">string</M15_19>
    <M15_20 KnZ="7.6"></M15_20>
    <M15_21 KnZ="59.27">79995</M15_21>
    <M15_22 KnZ="16.93">string</M15_22>
    <M15_23 KnZ="82.7">7</M15_23>
    <M15_24 KnZ="6.9">659</M15_24>
    <M15_26 KnZ="37.4">11</M15_26>
    <M15_27 KnZ="2.2">719</M15_27>
    <M15_28 KnZ="76.59">810</M15_28>
    <M15_29 KnZ="2.01">9179</M15_29>
    <M15_30 KnZ="2.57">5401</M15_30>
    <M15_31 KnZ="98.92">1981-04-21T16:37:08.82</M15_31>
    <M15_32 KnZ="7.93">32376237</M15_32>
    <M15_33 KnZ="9.97">string</M15_33>
    <M15_34 KnZ="8.95">string</M15_34>
  </Mod15>
  <Mod16>
    <M16_1 KnZ="8.95">2013-05-26T09:03:34.03</M16_1>
    <M16_2 KnZ="3.4">1</M16_2>
    <M16_3 KnZ="9.73">8</M16_3>
    <M16_4 KnZ="94.79">72</M16_4>
    <M16_5 KnZ="9.60">83</M16_5>
    <M16_6 KnZ="20.6">7</M16_6>
    <M16_7 KnZ="93.24">21</M16_7>
    <M16_8 KnZ="8.5">6601</M16_8>
    <M16_9 KnZ="42.01">string</M16_9>
    <M16_10 KnZ="29.37">string</M16_10>
  </Mod16>
  <Mod16>
    <M16_1 KnZ="7.5">2008-05-06T13:35:51.13</M16_1>
    <M16_2 KnZ="5.2">7</M16_2>
    <M16_3 KnZ="6.8">4</M16_3>
    <M16_4 KnZ="9.0">8</M16_4>
    <M16_5 KnZ="0.1">7</M16_5>
    <M16_6 KnZ="36.9">46</M16_6>
    <M16_7 KnZ="5.9">11</M16_7>
    <M16_8 KnZ="1.05">9791</M16_8>
    <M16_9 KnZ="94.20">string</M16_9>
    <M16_10 KnZ="71.3">string</M16_10>
  </Mod16>
  <Mod16>
    <M16_1 KnZ="8.51">2003-12-09T12:00:57.08</M16_1>
    <M16_2 KnZ="92.41">7</M16_2>
    <M16_3 KnZ="23.6">2</M16_3>
    <M16_4 KnZ="90.1">58</M16_4>
    <M16_5 KnZ="1.0">1</M16_5>
    <M16_6 KnZ="73.5">76</M16_6>
    <M16_7 KnZ="7.02">4</M16_7>
    <M16_8 KnZ="43.21">1857</M16_8>
    <M16_9 KnZ="44.49">string</M16_9>
    <M16_10 KnZ="00.3">string</M16_10>
  </Mod16>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="91.5">7051582778</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="06.94">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="88.5">1973-05-14T10:32:08.69</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="38.74">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="0.67">1993-06-11</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="19.0">2015-09-15</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="4.15">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="15.3">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="7.1">7331127501</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="09.7">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="0.51">1977-03-16T06:14:25.52</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="6.0">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="6.94">1988-11-13</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="49.9">1973-11-08</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="15.92">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="31.32">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="1.27">0889227931</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="1.3">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="83.9">2007-04-25T10:50:57.58</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="44.7">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="77.8">2003-12-17</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="95.4">2003-09-10</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="0.5">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="10.99">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="4.4">785I231751</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="60.59">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="75.36">1986-04-21T06:35:41.99</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="6.9">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="2.9">1971-04-23</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="68.1">1970-10-16</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="8.70">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="2.9">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="40.88">361x328583</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="37.1">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="7.26">2015-02-15T18:24:22.56</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="0.4">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="0.27">2010-05-18</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="3.13">1977-08-26</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="6.8">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="0.9">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod18>
    <M18_1 KnZ="7.60">891_193121</M18_1>
    <M18_2 KnZ="8.81">48213BG9962640</M18_2>
    <M18_3 KnZ="1.29">string</M18_3>
    <M18_4 KnZ="1.84">1981-11-10T04:34:42.14</M18_4>
    <M18_6 KnZ="2.3">574003.23</M18_6>
    <M18_7 KnZ="1.69">716121.23</M18_7>
    <M18_8 KnZ="2.9">244879.23</M18_8>
    <M18_9 KnZ="7.7">995622.22</M18_9>
    <M18_10 KnZ="10.76">480830.23</M18_10>
    <M18_11 KnZ="29.96">537223.23</M18_11>
    <M18_12 KnZ="8.9">315441.23</M18_12>
    <M18_13 KnZ="58.63">830201.23</M18_13>
    <M18_14 KnZ="11.3">784861.23</M18_14>
    <M18_15 KnZ="8.1">617589.23</M18_15>
    <M18_16 KnZ="5.15">655490.23</M18_16>
    <M18_17 KnZ="22.2">397393.23</M18_17>
    <M18_18 KnZ="6.9">299696.23</M18_18>
    <M18_19 KnZ="62.93">584218.23</M18_19>
    <M18_20 KnZ="75.3">string</M18_20>
    <M18_21 KnZ="2.72">string</M18_21>
  </Mod18>
  <Mod18>
    <M18_1 KnZ="7.6">0968249753</M18_1>
    <M18_2 KnZ="10.9">40187BG7209368</M18_2>
    <M18_3 KnZ="49.54">string</M18_3>
    <M18_4 KnZ="9.3">1999-05-09T06:59:51.96</M18_4>
    <M18_6 KnZ="92.02">163860.23</M18_6>
    <M18_7 KnZ="22.78">394314.23</M18_7>
    <M18_8 KnZ="4.5">33738.23</M18_8>
    <M18_9 KnZ="20.65">849665.23</M18_9>
    <M18_10 KnZ="6.4">260719.23</M18_10>
    <M18_11 KnZ="24.29">845075.23</M18_11>
    <M18_12 KnZ="7.2">976291.23</M18_12>
    <M18_13 KnZ="29.5">109199.23</M18_13>
    <M18_14 KnZ="70.93">359511.23</M18_14>
    <M18_15 KnZ="08.22">36771.23</M18_15>
    <M18_16 KnZ="94.05">357102.23</M18_16>
    <M18_17 KnZ="06.7">721879.23</M18_17>
    <M18_18 KnZ="37.4">704059.23</M18_18>
    <M18_19 KnZ="13.34">650454.23</M18_19>
    <M18_20 KnZ="2.3">string</M18_20>
    <M18_21 KnZ="1.9">string</M18_21>
  </Mod18>
</xsozial-ba>
```