# How to create an XML file via the following XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-serialization

Based on the Schema i'm supposed to build an XML File looking exactly like the XML File i show below, i'm not able to change the structure or anything about it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsozial-ba xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Mod0>
    <M0_1 KnZ="27.92">99079</M0_1>
    <M0_2 KnZ="2.55">72</M0_2>
    <M0_3 KnZ="8.88">XSozial-BA-SGBII-Version-4.7.0</M0_3>
    <M0_4 KnZ="42.7">B</M0_4>
    <M0_5 KnZ="43.3">2?"i@+O** Q").9</M0_5>
    <M0_6 KnZ="01.5">1993-12</M0_6>
    <M0_7 KnZ="2.50">2</M0_7>
    <M0_8 KnZ="6.4">1991-10-15T07:49:42.41</M0_8>
    <M0_9 KnZ="5.7">string</M0_9>
    <M0_10 KnZ="0.2">string</M0_10>
    <M0_11 KnZ="96.31">string</M0_11>
  </Mod0>
  <Mod1>
    <M1_3 KnZ="4.39">1972-03-15T01:07:11.07</M1_3>
    <M1_4 KnZ="7.9">2018-06-23</M1_4>
    <M1_5 KnZ="79.9">1990-09-20</M1_5>
    <M1_6 KnZ="2.5">3073880</M1_6>
    <M1_8 KnZ="60.2">4130920</M1_8>
    <M1_9 KnZ="1.9">336810</M1_9>
    <M1_10 KnZ="69.94">4515090</M1_10>
    <M1_12 KnZ="40.91">-4127340</M1_12>
    <M1_19 KnZ="1.40">858060</M1_19>
    <M1_32 KnZ="55.38">4615830</M1_32>
    <M1_34 KnZ="73.56">210160</M1_34>
    <M1_35 KnZ="9.08">-3908580</M1_35>
    <M1_36 KnZ="9.9">-2980490</M1_36>
    <M1_37 KnZ="8.3">2025480</M1_37>
    <M1_38 KnZ="90.9">-2365230</M1_38>
    <M1_39 KnZ="9.80">4466820</M1_39>
    <M1_40 KnZ="5.37">519040</M1_40>
    <M1_41 KnZ="37.92">872340</M1_41>
    <M1_42 KnZ="02.82">2558650</M1_42>
    <M1_43 KnZ="4.12">1821630</M1_43>
    <M1_44 KnZ="23.7">2068090</M1_44>
    <M1_45 KnZ="8.62">2416020</M1_45>
    <M1_46 KnZ="57.25">-1816340</M1_46>
    <M1_47 KnZ="93.79">-4509440</M1_47>
    <M1_48 KnZ="6.50">4405600</M1_48>
    <M1_49 KnZ="6.5">-235070</M1_49>
    <M1_50 KnZ="0.72">string</M1_50>
    <M1_51 KnZ="07.04">string</M1_51>
  </Mod1>
  <Mod2>
    <M2_1 KnZ="7.84">81788BG1441265</M2_1>
    <M2_25 KnZ="48.7">string</M2_25>
    <M2_3 KnZ="5.09">7</M2_3>
    <M2_4 KnZ="4.3">2018-05-17T09:18:32.82</M2_4>
    <M2_7 KnZ="0.49">1997-12-15</M2_7>
    <M2_10 KnZ="17.8">2011-05-21</M2_10>
    <M2_11 KnZ="79.0">78</M2_11>
    <M2_12 KnZ="54.5">9</M2_12>
    <M2_13 KnZ="59.3">6</M2_13>
    <M2_14 KnZ="61.0">16</M2_14>
    <M2_16 KnZ="01.23">532616.23</M2_16>
    <M2_17 KnZ="0.3">696766.23</M2_17>
    <M2_18 KnZ="10.73">789585.23</M2_18>
    <M2_26 KnZ="70.8">2010-03-05</M2_26>
    <M2_27 KnZ="09.3">2005</M2_27>
    <M2_28 KnZ="1.49">743031.23</M2_28>
    <M2_29 KnZ="3.18">172483.23</M2_29>
    <M2_30 KnZ="7.59">684711.23</M2_30>
    <M2_31 KnZ="3.16">string</M2_31>
    <M2_32 KnZ="8.27">string</M2_32>
  </Mod2>
  <Mod3>
    <M3_1 KnZ="86.2">2234138078</M3_1>
    <M3_2 KnZ="7.0">46048BG6406738</M3_2>
    <M3_34 KnZ="9.7">string</M3_34>
    <M3_3 KnZ="56.6">9</M3_3>
    <M3_4 KnZ="71.47">1994-07-12T21:35:55.77</M3_4>
    <M3_5 KnZ="92.33">string</M3_5>
    <M3_6 KnZ="8.4">string</M3_6>
    <M3_7 KnZ="3.40">string</M3_7>
    <M3_8 KnZ="46.0">string</M3_8>
    <M3_9 KnZ="0.8">string</M3_9>
    <M3_10 KnZ="4.26">ABC</M3_10>
    <M3_11 KnZ="82.07">string</M3_11>
    <M3_12 KnZ="27.15">string</M3_12>
    <M3_13 KnZ="55.42">73388</M3_13>
    <M3_14 KnZ="62.55">string</M3_14>
    <M3_18 KnZ="5.3">1992-01-03</M3_18>
    <M3_19 KnZ="9.5">W</M3_19>
    <M3_20 KnZ="5.2">hv_1Zv_cR7_2</M3_20>
    <M3_21 KnZ="89.05">132</M3_21>
    <M3_22 KnZ="5.34">4</M3_22>
    <M3_24 KnZ="45.4">4</M3_24>
    <M3_26 KnZ="7.4">9</M3_26>
    <M3_29 KnZ="90.05">false</M3_29>
    <M3_35 KnZ="05.4">03</M3_35>
    <M3_36 KnZ="18.89">true</M3_36>
    <M3_37 KnZ="77.28">1</M3_37>
    <M3_38 KnZ="38.6">77</M3_38>
    <M3_39 KnZ="09.71">7</M3_39>
    <M3_40 KnZ="7.5">1</M3_40>
    <M3_41 KnZ="5.9">9</M3_41>
    <M3_43 KnZ="25.54">5</M3_43>
    <M3_45 KnZ="81.3">string</M3_45>
    <M3_46 KnZ="6.2">string</M3_46>
  </Mod3>
  <Mod4>
    <M4_1 KnZ="04.67">516C002312</M4_1>
    <M4_2 KnZ="8.27">85358BG1042986</M4_2>
    <M4_9 KnZ="9.7">string</M4_9>
    <M4_3 KnZ="69.1">6</M4_3>
    <M4_4 KnZ="49.60">1998-06-12T06:22:53.10</M4_4>
    <M4_5 KnZ="2.4">438</M4_5>
    <M4_6 KnZ="81.8">226308.23</M4_6>
    <M4_7 KnZ="35.45">1991-06-01</M4_7>
    <M4_8 KnZ="41.8">1988-09-26</M4_8>
    <M4_10 KnZ="1.66">string</M4_10>
    <M4_11 KnZ="8.93">string</M4_11>
  </Mod4>
  <Mod5>
    <M5_1 KnZ="82.9">8398640296</M5_1>
    <M5_2 KnZ="64.2">98431BG8790232</M5_2>
    <M5_9 KnZ="2.1">string</M5_9>
    <M5_3 KnZ="0.0">6</M5_3>
    <M5_4 KnZ="62.4">2019-03-22T15:17:14.43</M5_4>
    <M5_5 KnZ="20.04">145</M5_5>
    <M5_6 KnZ="6.93">70433.23</M5_6>
    <M5_10 KnZ="36.4">58</M5_10>
    <M5_11 KnZ="40.8">126736.23</M5_11>
    <M5_13 KnZ="33.30">string</M5_13>
    <M5_14 KnZ="5.73">string</M5_14>
  </Mod5>
  <Mod7>
    <M7_1 KnZ="82.1">423_519620</M7_1>
    <M7_2 KnZ="03.0">48032BG3955047</M7_2>
    <M7_12 KnZ="5.2">string</M7_12>
    <M7_3 KnZ="21.14">8</M7_3>
    <M7_4 KnZ="84.42">2002-09-12T07:42:56.87</M7_4>
    <M7_6 KnZ="56.4">565598.23</M7_6>
    <M7_8 KnZ="9.03">10</M7_8>
    <M7_9 KnZ="4.1">988534.23</M7_9>
    <M7_10 KnZ="1.2">766323.23</M7_10>
    <M7_14 KnZ="0.4">268945.23</M7_14>
    <M7_15 KnZ="4.7">36217.23</M7_15>
    <M7_16 KnZ="71.22">string</M7_16>
    <M7_17 KnZ="63.8">string</M7_17>
  </Mod7>
  <Mod8>
    <M8_1 KnZ="77.31">915B189370</M8_1>
    <M8_2 KnZ="2.9">11439BG3859455</M8_2>
    <M8_10 KnZ="66.17">string</M8_10>
    <M8_3 KnZ="5.0">4</M8_3>
    <M8_4 KnZ="63.5">1996-03-28T14:55:21.87</M8_4>
    <M8_6 KnZ="9.02">318</M8_6>
    <M8_7 KnZ="5.12">955557.23</M8_7>
    <M8_8 KnZ="57.4">2018-03-05</M8_8>
    <M8_9 KnZ="89.8">1977-04-08</M8_9>
    <M8_11 KnZ="48.5">string</M8_11>
    <M8_12 KnZ="7.33">string</M8_12>
    <M8_13 KnZ="52.4">string</M8_13>
  </Mod8>
  <Mod10>
    <M10_1 KnZ="78.54">820m873680</M10_1>
    <M10_20 KnZ="5.27">string</M10_20>
    <M10_4 KnZ="00.84">1998-01-21T15:54:38.32</M10_4>
    <M10_5 KnZ="83.6">5</M10_5>
    <M10_6 KnZ="86.0">2005-10-09</M10_6>
    <M10_7 KnZ="7.9">2002-06-03</M10_7>
    <M10_8 KnZ="47.19">15</M10_8>
    <M10_9 KnZ="30.45">97</M10_9>
    <M10_10 KnZ="2.1">1974</M10_10>
    <M10_13 KnZ="77.65">false</M10_13>
    <M10_16 KnZ="69.44">1987-06-19</M10_16>
    <M10_21 KnZ="2.6">8</M10_21>
    <M10_23 KnZ="0.31">7</M10_23>
    <M10_28 KnZ="36.20">40158938</M10_28>
    <M10_29 KnZ="3.2">95338014</M10_29>
    <M10_30 KnZ="2.0">1993-03-20T00:55:27.15</M10_30>
    <M10_31 KnZ="67.5">2</M10_31>
    <M10_32 KnZ="0.13">true</M10_32>
    <M10_33 KnZ="7.06">7</M10_33>
    <M10_34 KnZ="10.34">string</M10_34>
    <M10_35 KnZ="10.35">string</M10_35>
  </Mod10>
  <Mod11>
    <M11_1 KnZ="80.33">074l382106</M11_1>
    <M11_11 KnZ="8.2">string</M11_11>
    <M11_4 KnZ="3.21">2005-01-22T01:35:47.34</M11_4>
    <M11_5 KnZ="05.4">1998-11-08</M11_5>
    <M11_6 KnZ="9.55">2011-10-28</M11_6>
    <M11_7 KnZ="2.14">5</M11_7>
    <M11_10 KnZ="64.93">54</M11_10>
    <M11_14 KnZ="14.42">87447767</M11_14>
    <M11_15 KnZ="52.15">17</M11_15>
    <M11_16 KnZ="11.56">1996-06-03T03:46:31.43</M11_16>
    <M11_17 KnZ="52.0">false</M11_17>
    <M11_18 KnZ="43.66">string</M11_18>
    <M11_19 KnZ="1.4">string</M11_19>
  </Mod11>
  <Mod12>
    <M12_1 KnZ="59.48">711H885079</M12_1>
    <M12_15 KnZ="20.78">string</M12_15>
    <M12_4 KnZ="74.21">1982-09-23T12:16:04.42</M12_4>
    <M12_5 KnZ="9.6">1</M12_5>
    <M12_10 KnZ="45.25">0</M12_10>
    <M12_16 KnZ="3.1">2</M12_16>
    <M12_17 KnZ="6.8">5</M12_17>
    <M12_18 KnZ="9.7">true</M12_18>
    <M12_19 KnZ="0.3">string</M12_19>
    <M12_20 KnZ="97.5">string</M12_20>
  </Mod12>
  <Mod13>
    <M13_1 KnZ="0.75">738D383042</M13_1>
    <M13_33 KnZ="6.6">string</M13_33>
    <M13_4 KnZ="66.29">2006-11-24T12:58:05.00</M13_4>
    <M13_5 KnZ="2.79">1990-01-28</M13_5>
    <M13_7 KnZ="1.6">1981-02-13</M13_7>
    <M13_8 KnZ="3.76">2067</M13_8>
    <M13_10 KnZ="36.9">50</M13_10>
    <M13_12 KnZ="5.6">09845139</M13_12>
    <M13_13 KnZ="47.61">421479.23</M13_13>
    <M13_16 KnZ="61.4">5</M13_16>
    <M13_35 KnZ="86.95">string</M13_35>
    <M13_36 KnZ="1.0">28</M13_36>
    <M13_37 KnZ="12.4">1998-07-21T04:31:32.86</M13_37>
    <M13_38 KnZ="6.8">79296731</M13_38>
    <M13_39 KnZ="80.56">7</M13_39>
    <M13_40 KnZ="63.8">string</M13_40>
    <M13_41 KnZ="48.7">string</M13_41>
  </Mod13>
  <Mod14>
    <M14_1 KnZ="6.4">944c687231</M14_1>
    <M14_18 KnZ="88.8">string</M14_18>
    <M14_4 KnZ="71.28">1994-07-11T02:46:34.93</M14_4>
    <M14_7 KnZ="34.1">57</M14_7>
    <M14_14 KnZ="4.1">1980-07-27</M14_14>
    <M14_15 KnZ="03.8">1972-02-06</M14_15>
    <M14_16 KnZ="9.9">2008-04-02</M14_16>
    <M14_17 KnZ="1.7">1988-05-03</M14_17>
    <M14_19 KnZ="76.5">string</M14_19>
    <M14_20 KnZ="8.56">string</M14_20>
  </Mod14>
  <Mod15>
    <M15_1 KnZ="5.24">2016-03-10T11:18:31.47</M15_1>
    <M15_4 KnZ="2.1">1330</M15_4>
    <M15_5 KnZ="74.7">4850</M15_5>
    <M15_6 KnZ="52.74">94</M15_6>
    <M15_7 KnZ="9.5">4124</M15_7>
    <M15_8 KnZ="14.2">string</M15_8>
    <M15_9 KnZ="00.11">1981-08-07</M15_9>
    <M15_10 KnZ="79.0">1982-09-11</M15_10>
    <M15_11 KnZ="51.7">52</M15_11>
    <M15_15 KnZ="53.41">99914</M15_15>
    <M15_16 KnZ="56.31">string</M15_16>
    <M15_17 KnZ="54.72">string</M15_17>
    <M15_18 KnZ="91.12">69730972</M15_18>
    <M15_19 KnZ="81.7">string</M15_19>
    <M15_20 KnZ="7.6"></M15_20>
    <M15_21 KnZ="59.27">79995</M15_21>
    <M15_22 KnZ="16.93">string</M15_22>
    <M15_23 KnZ="82.7">7</M15_23>
    <M15_24 KnZ="6.9">659</M15_24>
    <M15_26 KnZ="37.4">11</M15_26>
    <M15_27 KnZ="2.2">719</M15_27>
    <M15_28 KnZ="76.59">810</M15_28>
    <M15_29 KnZ="2.01">9179</M15_29>
    <M15_30 KnZ="2.57">5401</M15_30>
    <M15_31 KnZ="98.92">1981-04-21T16:37:08.82</M15_31>
    <M15_32 KnZ="7.93">32376237</M15_32>
    <M15_33 KnZ="9.97">string</M15_33>
    <M15_34 KnZ="8.95">string</M15_34>
  </Mod15>
  <Mod16>
    <M16_1 KnZ="7.5">2008-05-06T13:35:51.13</M16_1>
    <M16_2 KnZ="5.2">7</M16_2>
    <M16_3 KnZ="6.8">4</M16_3>
    <M16_4 KnZ="9.0">8</M16_4>
    <M16_5 KnZ="0.1">7</M16_5>
    <M16_6 KnZ="36.9">46</M16_6>
    <M16_7 KnZ="5.9">11</M16_7>
    <M16_8 KnZ="1.05">9791</M16_8>
    <M16_9 KnZ="94.20">string</M16_9>
    <M16_10 KnZ="71.3">string</M16_10>
  </Mod16>
  <Mod17>
    <M17_1 KnZ="40.88">361x328583</M17_1>
    <M17_3 KnZ="37.1">string</M17_3>
    <M17_4 KnZ="7.26">2015-02-15T18:24:22.56</M17_4>
    <M17_5 KnZ="0.4">string</M17_5>
    <M17_6 KnZ="0.27">2010-05-18</M17_6>
    <M17_7 KnZ="3.13">1977-08-26</M17_7>
    <M17_8 KnZ="6.8">string</M17_8>
    <M17_9 KnZ="0.9">string</M17_9>
  </Mod17>
  <Mod18>
    <M18_1 KnZ="7.60">891_193121</M18_1>
    <M18_2 KnZ="8.81">48213BG9962640</M18_2>
    <M18_3 KnZ="1.29">string</M18_3>
    <M18_4 KnZ="1.84">1981-11-10T04:34:42.14</M18_4>
    <M18_6 KnZ="2.3">574003.23</M18_6>
    <M18_7 KnZ="1.69">716121.23</M18_7>
    <M18_8 KnZ="2.9">244879.23</M18_8>
    <M18_9 KnZ="7.7">995622.22</M18_9>
    <M18_10 KnZ="10.76">480830.23</M18_10>
    <M18_11 KnZ="29.96">537223.23</M18_11>
    <M18_12 KnZ="8.9">315441.23</M18_12>
    <M18_13 KnZ="58.63">830201.23</M18_13>
    <M18_14 KnZ="11.3">784861.23</M18_14>
    <M18_15 KnZ="8.1">617589.23</M18_15>
    <M18_16 KnZ="5.15">655490.23</M18_16>
    <M18_17 KnZ="22.2">397393.23</M18_17>
    <M18_18 KnZ="6.9">299696.23</M18_18>
    <M18_19 KnZ="62.93">584218.23</M18_19>
    <M18_20 KnZ="75.3">string</M18_20>
    <M18_21 KnZ="2.72">string</M18_21>
  </Mod18>
</xsozial-ba>
```

What i did is to use the xsd.exe Tool like in this explanation to create a class from the XSD that i have: [Generating XML file using XSD file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530424/generating-xml-file-using-xsd-file)

Now i got my class without having to code it myself. But.. how do i code the Serialization now? Is that even possible because the element names are dynamic? And if it is, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the root class (xsozial-ba) and add values to the instance.  The class structure is not dynamic, only the values.  The serializer code would look like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            xsozial_ba xsozial_ba = new xsozial_ba()
            {
                Mod0 = new Mod0()
                {
                    M0_1 = new M0_1() { KnZ = 27.92M, value = "99079" }
                }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(xsozial_ba));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, xsozial_ba);
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "xsozial-ba")]
    public class xsozial_ba
    {
        public Mod0 Mod0 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Mod0
    {
        public M0_1 M0_1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class M0_1
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public decimal KnZ { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As i'm new to programming i'd need some more help. Could you show me how that works with the XML shown above for Mod1, M1_1 and the Attribute KnZ and fill the Value with whatever string i want so I can do it for all the other Mods? I'd very much appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I got two more questions. How can i add to my code to not write an Element without a value into the XML? For example if i have M0_1, M0_2 & M0_3 but only 1 & 3 are filled so i want the XML to only generate 1 & 3. And also, if Mod0 has no Elements at all(because all Elements are not filled for example), how do i leave that out then? I tried out a few things already but they didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Xml Serialization automatically generates all the elements.  you would have to write a custom serialize to leave element out.